# How does ioctl exactly exactly work and how to make it work properly for dvd readings?

Tags: c, hardware, ioctl

I've done the following code to test the use of ioctl and I'm pretty confused about the results.

```
int main(void)
{
    int id;
    dvd_struct s;
    id=open("/dev/dvd",O_RDONLY);
    ioctl(id,DVD_READ_STRUCT,&s);
    printf("%d,%s,%s",s.bca.len,s.manufact.value,s.disckey.value);
    close(id);
 }
```

First of all in manufact and disckey value rare symbols appear, but that wouldn't be that important, if it weren't because any time I run the program a new value appears, despite always keeping the dvd in the dvd player. Even bca.len varies in each execution, although it's true that it alway gives a number above 32000 and lower than 33000.

Finally the results are given whether there's an inserted dvd or not, so I wonder where it's getting exactly those results from, even if it's reading the dvd.

The dvd is being recognized by the operating system, as a cat /dev/dvd displays it's content in a fine way.

Can someone explain why is it working that way and if I could make it work appropiately (I mean, getting the same results at least for manufact and disckey values and making sure the info is taken from the inserted dvd?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: I don't know anything about the ioctl and how to use thist struct, but this seems useful. http://www.tldp.org/LDP/lkmpg/2.4/html/x856.html

Answer (score 2):

Check the return value of `ioctl`. If it fails `s` will not filled with infos.

```
if (ioctl(id, DVD_READ_STRUCT, &s) < 0) 
{
   perror("DVD_READ_STRUCT");
   return -1;
}
```

[Man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl.2.html)

```
RETURN VALUE   

       Usually, on success zero is returned.  A few ioctl() requests use the
       return value as an output parameter and return a nonnegative value on
       success.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.
ERRORS 

       EBADF  fd is not a valid descriptor.

       EFAULT argp references an inaccessible memory area.

       EINVAL request or argp is not valid.

       ENOTTY fd is not associated with a character special device.

       ENOTTY The specified request does not apply to the kind of object
              that the descriptor fd references.
```

BTW always check return values of non void function.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, for your tips, I got to solve it via a code similar to this one that is inserted before the ioctl call:

```
memset(&s, 0, sizeof(s));
s.type = DVD_STRUCT_MANUFACT;
```

You must set a type for s and you'll get the ones related to that type and do the same for every otrher type.